# Extract Sound from translate.google.com

Tags: google-chrome, audio

Bunenas tardes señores!

For many years I extract sound from google.translate.com by Chrome DevTools and the Network tab. When click the sound button in the Network tab mp3 file appears. I just click on it and download for further educational purposes.

Now (literally today) there only XHR type files with countless character sequences inside square brackets as like as strings in JS arrays. And page itself is quite complicated.

How to extract sound in new circumstance?

- Some how extract from XHR files.
- May be some way to record in GNU/Linux sound system.
- Or something else.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

php code doing this:

```php
<?php

$lang = 'en';
$text = 'hello world';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://translate.google.com/_/TranslateWebserverUi/data/batchexecute',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query([
        'f.req' => json_encode([
            [
                [
                    'jQ1olc',
                    json_encode([
                        $text,
                        $lang,
                        null,
                        json_encode(null),
                    ]),
                    null,
                    'generic',
                ]
            ]
        ]),
    ]),
]);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($response && preg_match('#//NE[^\\\\]+#', $response, $matches)) {
    file_put_contents('test.mp3', base64_decode($matches[0]));
}
else {
    echo "error\n";
}
```

Comment: Tested with linux and docker `docker run -it php:7.4-cli bash` . You are a hero. I will port yur code to java and nodejs. Thanks

Comment: Working as expected. This should be accepted answer.

Comment: @JRichardsz Did you port the code to Java?

Comment: No yet  :( sorry

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Maybe Google already changed the API.

Answer (score 2):

### How to extract sound from translate.google.com Base64 response.

1. Visit translate.google.com, run Chrome DevTools by F12 key, enter the Network tab. Enter a text and press enter to make sound button appears. Click the sound button.
2. Select a largest `xhr` request to `batchexecute?rpcids...` it would be several kB, these kind of `xhr` responses contains mp3 encoded in base64.
3. At the Response tab of this request would be a long string in an array surrounded by square brackets and escaped double quotes `"[\"//NExAAR...VV\"]"`, purge this string from brackets and quiotes to get something like `//NExAAR...VV` and save it ingo `sound.base64` file.
4. Then decode text from `sound.base64` into a mp3 file by this command:

```
base64 -d sound.base64 > 1.mp3
```

5. To listen mp3 from the terminal next command may be used:

```
mpg123 1.mp3
```

OR

Use https://soundoftext.com/ or test https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell#usage Audio Options.

UPD:

```
curl ... | grep -oP '\[\["wrb.fr","jQ1olc","\[\\"\K(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?' | base64 -d > /tmp/123.mp3
```

thanks for code to @alukardd.

It is possible to make a right click on the request in the Chrome DevTools: Copy => copy as cURL.

thanks for information to @fjewo.

Comment: This is no longer supported by Google Translate in the browser via inspect element. The functionality to download an mp3 file of a translation voice output from a browser's developer window has been removed.

Comment: batchexecute is invoked but the response is a json with errors :S https://i.ibb.co/J3ypP60/google-translate-sound-ajax.png

Answer (score 1):

A quick alternative - If you are on Mac OSx, you could also install SoundFlower and re-route the audio output to a DAW or just QuickTime player.

https://soundflower.en.softonic.com/mac

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working AD 2023 example in python to grab mp3 from google translate:

```py
import re
import requests
import json
import base64

lang = 'en'
text = 'hello world'

data = {
    'f.req': json.dumps([
        [
            [
                'jQ1olc',
                json.dumps([
                    text,
                    lang,
                    None,
                    json.dumps(None),
                ]),
                None,
                'generic',
            ]
        ]
    ]),
}

response = requests.post('https://translate.google.com/_/TranslateWebserverUi/data/batchexecute', data=data)

if response.status_code == 200:
    match = re.search(r'//NE[^\\\\]+', response.text)
    if match:
        with open('test.mp3', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(base64.b64decode(match.group(0)))
    else:
        print('error Match')
else:
    print('error HTTP')
```